# how many databases can I create in a mongodb instance?

Tags: mongodb

app context:

1. Login user could define their own business schema.
2. some user could have pb scale data， some user could have mb  scale data.
3. more users is always better ：）
4. mongodb 4.2

questions：

1. create a database for a user or create collections for a user?
2. pros and cons
3. what  is database in mongodb，a name space for collections?
4. wired tiger focus on instance?  database?

thanks ahead.